# Calculation of digits

Tags: arithmetic

Suppose that an array of numbers from $1$ to $10^{23}$ is given. Let's calculate the sum of digits of each number. What kind of numbers among them are more with a $3$-digit sum or a $2$-digit sum? 
Please give me detailed explanation, because I do not have any idea how to approach this task.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- It would be easier to look at numbers from $0$ through to $10^{23}-1$, though this makes minimal difference
- How many digits does the largest number have?  What is the largest possible digit sum?
- What is the average digit sum (you can include leading zeros if it helps)? Can you pair numbers with digit sums below this with numbers with digit sums above this? What is the median digit sum? What is the answer to the original question?

Comment: Thanks! You hint that one can consider all numbers as 23-bit numbers. The largest number 99…99 consists of 23 nines and the largest possible digit sum is 23*9=207. The average digit sum (0+9)/2=4,5*23=103,5. So, the numbers with the sum of digits 103 and less is the same as with the sum of digits 104 and more. Therefore, numbers with the sum of digits less than 100, that is, two-digit, will be less than numbers with the sum of digits greater than or equal to 100, that is, three-digit.
Answer: there will be more numbers with a three-digit sum of digits.

Comment: Let’s S(k) define the amount of such numbers with the sum of digits equal to k. If each digit is replaced by "opposite, i.e. complementary to 9", i.e. x by 9-x, then we get a number with the sum of digits 23*9-k=207-k instead of k. It follows that S(k)=S(207-k). In particular, the number of two-digit sum numbers is S(10)+S(11)+...+S(99)=S(197)+S(196)+...+S(108), which is obviously less than S(100)+S(101)+...+S(207), that is, the number of numbers with a three-digit sum.

Comment: Is that the right way of thinking?

Comment: @Anatol - Yes - that is the way I was thinking

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!